# checking for existing and defined element

Tags: javascript

Say

```
var elem = document.getElementById ('anId');
```

Does

```
if (elem) ...
```

give same result as

```
if (typeof elem !== "undefined"  &&  elem != null) ...
```

i.e. can I replace the second by the first?

Comment: Yes you can. The second one is already too verbose, `if (elem != null)` would suffice.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Not  in every case!

Comment: Not if there is a possibility that `elem` is not *declared*, but if `elem` is `undefined` or `null`, `elem != null` would be `false`. However, there are seldom situations where a variable is not even declared.

Comment: And in this code, as we can see the declaration, just the `!= null` is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In the example you gave, you can safely check for whether you got back an element reference or `null` using your first example.

The underlying mechanism is this: In JavaScript, everything can be coerced to a boolean value. Most things are "truthy" (they coerce to `true`). Some things are `falsey` (they coerce to `false`). The falsey values are `null`, `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `undefined`, and of course `false`. The truthy values are everything else, including all non-`null` object references. Since `getElementById` returns `null` if the element couldn't be found, and a reference to the DOM element if it could, your first test is safe.

Comment: Thanks, The first "Yes" was what I wanted to know, but of course I hoped to get some in-depth info, what you perfectliy gave me. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I did that now (I didn't check the page for a while, that's why it took some time...)

Answer (score 0):

Using `if(elem)` is acceptable, but keep in mind that `if(elem)` will not **always** give you the same result as `if (typeof elem !== "undefined"  &&  elem != null)`. There are *falsy* values in JavaScript that essentially evaluate to `false`.

For example, `if(elem)` wouldn't evaluate to `true` if the value of `elem` was `0`, but the second form would. The same thing would happen in the case of values like `NaN`, `""`, and `false`. The second check you is more specific because you are explicitly checking for `null` and `undefined` values. The first check is not as specific since it will coerce any value of `elem` to a boolean and then check to see if that value is `true` or `false`.

Comment: Thank you, this is why I didn't ask if it possible to replace "one by each other", but explicitly "the second by the first".